# list comprehension over tuple of tuple

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have the following string

conf=(("X", "X", "-"), ("O", "O", "-"), ("X", "X", "O"))

which is a tuple of tuple, I want to iterate over each element and find the "-" which means the empty space and return a tuple with the coordinate of the "-"

What I have tried so far, which does not work

```
conf=(("X", "X", "-"), ("O", "O", "-"), ("X", "X", "O"))
free_spaces = ((i,j) for i,j in range(3) if conf[i][j] == "-" )
free_spaces = {(x,y) for x in conf for y in conf if conf[x][y] == "-" }
```

can someone help with this one?

Answer (score 0):

Tweak your code a little and you will have your solution:

```
[(i,j) for i in range(len(conf)) for j in range(len(conf[i])) if conf[i][j]=='-' ]
```

If you are sure about the length of your tuple being 3 every time, you can skip the `len()`

Answer (score 0):

Returning -1 if "-" not in tuple; otherwise returning index.

```
conf=(("X", "X", "-"), ("O", "O", "-"), ("X", "X", "O"))

print([conf[i].index("-") if "-" in conf[i] else -1 for i in range(len(conf))])
```